# User Input is not recognized as integer

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a little to calculator which can add 2 numbers the user puts in on the website.

My function for adding the numbers and building the HTML and injecting it back in the HTML is working only my code is giving me back: "NaN" (Not a number)
[**Check out my code right here on JSFiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/66f4uakc/)

```
  var userInput1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput1').value);
  var userInput2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput2').value);
  var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
  var resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');
  var contentWrap = document.getElementById('contentWrap');


  var total = addTheseNumbers(userInput1, userInput2);


  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);


//build html and push to page
function buildHtml(){
    contentWrap.innerHTML = total;

  }



      //calculator
function addTheseNumbers(a, b)
{
 var sum = a + b;
 return sum;
}

      //handle user clicking the button
    function handleClick (event) 
    {
      if(document.getElementById('userInput1') == 0 && document.getElementById('userInput2') == 0){
            errorMessage.classList.remove('hidden')
      }  

      else {
          addTheseNumbers (userInput1, userInput2);
          buildHtml();
      }
}
```

I've tried a lot of methods, adding a + before document.getElementById and adding parseINT as well.
To check if the calculator function and the buildHTML function are working I've changed the var's to integers, once I do that, I get back the correct result.
This (probably) means the problems lies within the code not recognizing the user input as a number.

**Thank you in advance for all the help!**

Comment: You're getting the value before the user's actually typed anything in, you need to set `userInput1` and `userInput2` inside the click handler, and set `total` there as well, as again, you set `total` immediately before any values have been set

Comment: Also you are not getting values.. better use document.getElementById('userInput1').value in the handleClick function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable are cached at

```
  var userInput1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput1').value);
  var userInput2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput2').value);
```

So, they remain as they're even if the inputs are updated or modified. Here's what I changed

```
function buildHtml(total){ // added argument for better flexibility 
    contentWrap.innerHTML = total;
}
```

and

```
var total = addTheseNumbers(userInput1.value, userInput2.value);
```

Notice, I am calling `.value` again and passing them to `addTheseNumbers()`, then returns the sum.

Full working snippet;

```js
  var userInput1 = document.getElementById('userInput1');
  var userInput2 = document.getElementById('userInput2');
 var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
  var resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');
 var contentWrap = document.getElementById('contentWrap');

   button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
   // resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetButton);


function buildHtml(total){
    contentWrap.innerHTML = total;
}



  // function resetButton (event) {
  //     if(document.getElementById('userInput1').value == 0 && document.getElementById('userInput2').value == 0){
  //           errorMessage.classList.remove('hidden')
  //     } 
  //        }


      //calculator
function addTheseNumbers(a, b) {
 var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
 return sum;
}

    function handleClick (event) 
    {
      if(document.getElementById('userInput1') == 0 && document.getElementById('userInput2') == 0){
            errorMessage.classList.remove('hidden')
      }  

      else {
           var total = addTheseNumbers (userInput1.value, userInput2.value);
           buildHtml(total);
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HowToDoList</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         
         #errorMessage {
               color: #FF5d25;
               font-family: helvetica;
               font-weight: bold;
               visibility: visible;
               opacity: 1;
               transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
         
         .hidden {
               display: none;
         }
         
   .fadeOut{
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.83);
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: silver 3px 3px 5px 0px;
      border: 2px dashed yellow;
      padding: 3px;
    }
.myButton {
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff5c25), color-stop(1, #ff5c25));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5c25', endColorstr='#ff5c25',GradientType=0);
   background-color:#ff5c25;
   -moz-border-radius:28px;
   -webkit-border-radius:28px;
   border-radius:28px;
   border:1px solid #bab6ba;
   display:inline-block;
   cursor:pointer;
   color:#ffffff;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:17px;
   padding:4px 14px;
   text-decoration:none;
   text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
}
.myButton:hover {
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff5c25), color-stop(1, #ff5c25));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff5c25 5%, #ff5c25 100%);
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5c25', endColorstr='#ff5c25',GradientType=0);
   background-color:#ff5c25;
}
.myButton:focus { 
   outline:0 !important; 

}
.buttons {
    position: center;

}


        </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center><div>
<h1> Add These Numbers </h1>
<p class="hidden" class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage">You did not enter a value, please enter a value</p>
   <div id="contentWrap" position="center">
      <form>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="instructions">
            <input id="userInput1" type="number" name="userInput1">
            <input id="userInput2" type="number" name="userInput2">
         </div>
         <div class="buttons">
   <button id="myButton" class="myButton" a href="#" type="button">Calculate</button>
</div>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>

</center></div>

</body>
</html>
```